# problem AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Tags: object, attributes, attributeerror, sequential

i have problem with my code.
thanks
I can't get the correct result

```
dic = test_dataset.class_indices
idc = {k:v for v, k in dic.items()}

img = load_img('C:\\Users\\landa\\Downloads\\Alzheimer_s Dataset\\test\\NonDemented\\26 (100).jpg', target_size = (224,224,3))

img = img_to_array(img)`enter code here`
img = img/255
imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')

img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
answer = model.predict_classes(img)

probability = round(np.max(model.predict_proba(img)*100),2)
print(probability, '% chances are there that the image is',idc[answer[0]])
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.  Where is ```model``` defined?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.